# Mensaje de error en mi web: Estás a punto de enviar una información no segura

Tags: web, https, odoo, certificado-ssl, pfsense

tengo un sitio web en odoo, al cual al entrar para pagar me salta el siguiente error:

Estás a punto de enviar una información no segura
Dado que la conexión que usa este sitio web no es completamente segura, otros usuarios podrán ver tu información.

pero si le doy sobre el candado en la url, me sale que el certificiado está bien y no me sale ningún error, y no logro encontrar de que puede ser el fallo, alguien sabe a que se puede deber? no se si será cosa del pfsense o algo muchas gracias.

Comment: pueden ser varias cosas, entre otra que tu formulario se envíe a una url sin https. Pero sin ver mas difícil saber.

Comment: Tengo ciertos enlaces que mandan a http en vez de https, pero por ciertos motivos no puedo cambiarlos, como podría solucionar esto? que cada vez que llegue a una ruta http te mande a la misma ruta pero con https?? utilizando el pfsense o algo por el estilo, por código (js) ya probé pero no funciona

Comment: necesitas que los servidores donde llegan esas urls soporten https y enviar a la versión https, no hay otra forma... pero si esos servidores no aceptan https puedes hacer un proxy por encima que acepte https y haga la request a http internamente. pero es algo mas complejo

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que un sitio utilice algún recurso http (no seguro) ya sea que envié o reciba respuestas, automáticamente no es más seguro por obvias razones. Los datos de quien utilice ese sitio no son seguros y es obligatorio informárselo. Lo único que puedes hacer es buscar otros servicios https para sustituir los que tienes sin dicha protección y asegurar una verdadera protección a los usuarios de dicho sitio.